# Folding of the workspaces bar in Ubuntu 18.04 GNOME

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I'd like to know if there is a way to prevent the workspaces bar from "folding" when we press the Super button from the keyboard. 
This is the usual behaviour in Debian, but in Ubuntu the workspaces bar 'retracts' itself further on the right of the screen, just to 'come back to place' when you put the mouse over it. I would like for it to be always out like in Debian, and I wonder if there was a way to tweak this.

Thank you very much in advanvce

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever wonders, someone pointed me out an extension for Gnome Shell Extensions, which you can find here:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/503/always-zoom-workspaces/